# How to write pattern for preg_match_all in php

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have following html code, I want to extract the name and text in textarea. How can I do it?

```
Dear You've just received.<br><br><b> Name<br><br>Added:</b> 2012-07-14<br><br>Rating - 46%, Yes - 14, No - 16<br><br><TEXTAREA rows=5 cols=60 wrap>Text in textarea</textarea>
```

Please tell me how to do it and how to write patterns for preg_match so that I don't need to ask such questions again..

Answer (score 1):

Got the pattern-

```
/<br><br><b>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<TEXTAREA(.*?)>(.*?)<\/textarea>/i
```

Thanks to [Truth4oll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600086/truth4oll) and [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: If this is the solution to your question, please deem your question resolved by awarding the green tick to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for work with html:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html("Dear You've just received.<br><br><b> Name<br><br>Added:</b> 2012-07-14<br><br>Rating - 46%, Yes - 14, No - 16<br><br><TEXTAREA rows=5 cols=60 wrap>Text in textarea</textarea>");
echo $textarea = $html->find("textarea", 0)->innertext; //text of textarea
$name= $html->find("b",0)->innertext; //consist: 'Name<br><br>Added:'
preg_match ('/(\w+)/i',$name,$matche); 
echo $name = $matche[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out some regex simulators such as http://www.lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php and to build your pattern, take some time to study the Bible http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html.